# Can MySQL support database email?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, email

Can MySQL database support database email feature as in SQL Server? I am using community edition of MySQL. How can I send emails from database?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [long thread on the MySQL site](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,33635,33635#msg-33635) with several possible solutions, using triggers. The potential solutions differ, depending on what OS you're using.